# How to overcome the JQuery MultiSelect Performance Issue when there are many items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using JQuery Multiselect from JQuery UI: http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

It has great features for searching the items, option list and checkbox list, etc but

It doesn't perform well when the number of items are above 700 and it has CSS issues with IE 8.0.

Where can I find a multiselectable and searchable drop downlist that can perform good in large numbers? I googled but couldn't find anything that meets these criteria.

I'd like to avoid building a new such control myself if possible.

Comment: were you able to increase the performance? I'm in the same boat now and it really slows the application..

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off styling your own with css only. Shouldn't use JS if you don't have to. Here's the jsfiddle.com http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/4WRS2/2/

edit: I made it a little prettier: http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/4WRS2/4/

If you have any more questions, please ask.

```
<div class="multiselect">
    <ul>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="1"/><div>Test 1</div></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

The key points on the css are here.

```
.multiselect {...
    overflow: scroll;
    box-sizing: margin-box;
}
....
.multiselect li input[type="checkbox"]:checked~span {
    background: #efefef;
}
```